# Где идеологически правильно ставить фигурные скобки?

Tags: php, синтаксис

```
<?php
  if ($a < 100)
  {
    $a++;
  }
?>
```

или

```
<?php
  if ($a < 100) {
    $a++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: идеалогически правильно не ставить закрывающий `?>`, где ставить фигурные скобки - дело вкуса.

Comment: Если смотреть PSR-2, то там написано `Открывающая фигурная скобка в управляющих конструкциях ДОЛЖНА располагаться в той же строке, что и сама конструкция, а закрывающая фигурная скобка ДОЛЖНА располагаться на следующей строке после тела конструкции.` ...... но на самом деле это порой дело вкуса, а в некоторых компаниях порой обязывают соблюдать свой внутренний стандарт, в котором может быть совсем по-другому написано

Comment: Идеологически правильно ставить фигурные скобки **одинаково**. Главное не выбранный вариант, а целостность стиля.

Answer (score 2):

Есть стандарты написания кода [PSR-0, PSR-1, PSR-2, PSR-3, PSR-4](https://www.google.by/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHZL_ruBY723BY723&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=PSR-0%2C%20PSR-1%2C%20PSR-2%2C%20PSR-3%2C%20PSR-4). Там много всякого написано. Почитайте. Где-то первый вариант, а где-то второй (египетский стиль).

Comment: из них всего два имеют отношение к вопросу